# Error: UEFI setting must be the same for the instance and the boot disk. While editing the VM Instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Basically I want to take a backup of a VM machine in GCP and came to know about snapshot. So I am trying to use `snapshot` feature of `GCP` I created a snapshot of a machine called angular(this machine contain data of angular and node) here is the image of the snapshot:

[image: Snapshot details]

Now I want to use this snapshot to restored the data and I don't want to create a new instance, I get one way in which first you have to remove the boot disk of the instance in which you to restore the snapshot data and then create a new disk using that snapshot and then use that disk. I tried this technique but I am getting this error:

**Error:**

```
UEFI setting must be the same for the instance and the boot disk.
```

image of disk that I created using snapshot:

[image: Diks details]

**Image of VM instance in which I want to use the new disk (created from the snapshot)**:

[image: VM instance]

[image: VM instance]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you enabling vTPM and Integrity Monitoring (last screenshot)? Research what `Trusted Platform Module` provides and prevents.

Answer (score 5):

I think your instance might not be compatible with **UEFI**. On Google Cloud there are some images that are **UEFI** compatible and others that are not. You can check if your instance is UEFI compatible with the following command (put the correct zone):

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe your-instance --zone=europe-west4-b | grep type:
```

If the instance is compatible, you will see `type: UEFI_COMPATIBLE` as a result. If it is not compatible, you will not see it. I think that currently it is not possible to edit UEFI compatibility on an instance. However, you can check what images are UEFI compatible. Here are a couple of examples:

**Compatible:**

```
$ gcloud compute images describe-from-family rhel-7 --project=rhel-cloud  | grep type:
- type: UEFI_COMPATIBLE

$ gcloud compute images describe-from-family rhel-8 --project=rhel-cloud  | grep type:
- type: UEFI_COMPATIBLE
```

**Not Compatible:**

```
$ gcloud compute images describe-from-family debian-9 --project=debian-cloud  | grep type:
- type: VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE
```

You can see other images details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images).

Comment: Did you recently tried editing compatibility? Is grayed out for me. I created an instance with non uefi compatible Boot image, I detach it and want to  attach a new boot image that is UEFI compatible is it possible?

Answer (score -2):

This is due to you creating / migrating the other VM with a different disk configuration. Please detach all disks, note the VM configuration and delete it, then recreate the VM with the noted configurationg and existing disk.